# Conditions on a editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, settext

I'm a bit struggling with some editText :S I'd like to check with some conditions if the user has filled a field or not : my code just doesn't seem to work.

The code :

...

```
     input.setText("rrr");
     input2.setText("rrr");

     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);

     builder.setCancelable(true);
     builder.setTitle("Add a friend");
     builder.setMessage("Fill in the fields you know :");

     builder.setView(layout);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            if(input.getEditableText() != null && input2.getEditableText() != null && input3.getEditableText() != null){

                Dialog d = new Dialog(ctx);
                d.setTitle("BLiBLiBLi !");
                d.show();

            }else if(input.getEditableText() != null && input2.getEditableText() != null && input3.getEditableText() == null){

                Dialog d = new Dialog(ctx);
                d.setTitle("BLABLABLA !");
                d.show();

            }
```

...

as you can see, the first 2 fields are have a setText("rrr"); but not the third one...
So the second condition should point out (if I don't fill in the third input) and I should get the BLABLABLA message but I m always getting the BLiBLiBLi :'( (it's only a test of course :p)

I've already tried to change input.getEditableText() != null with input.getEditableText().toString != "" or setting the inputs like this input.setText(""); or input.setText(null); : it just doesn't work I always end up in the first condition that thinks all my fields have been filled in with something

Comment: Probably because it's not null, it's an empty string.  Have you tried setting a break point and examining the value?

Comment: I think what you want is to check if an edittext is empty, isn't it?

Comment: Please mark the correct answers in your old questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the length of text in each `EditText`. This will do what you want...

```
if(input.getText().toString().length() > 0 && input2.getText().toString().length() > 0 && input3.getText().toString().length() > 0 ){

    Dialog d = new Dialog(ctx);
    d.setTitle("BLiBLiBLi !");
    d.show();

} else if(input.getText().toString().length() > 0 && input2.getText().toString().length() > 0 && input3.getText().toString().length() == 0 ) {

    Dialog d = new Dialog(ctx);
    d.setTitle("BLABLABLA !");
    d.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you want is to check the length of the String in the EditText

```
if( EditText.getText().length() > 0 ){
    do something here if text exists
   }else{
    do something else here if empty
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change your `input.getText() != null` to `input.getText().toString().equals("")`. If the EditText field is empty, it means it contains an empty string (text=""), not null.

The simplest and "prettiest" way of doing so is using [TextUtils.isEmpty()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence))

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this way also.

```
    EditText usernameEditText = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
    sUsername = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
    if (sUsername.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```